# Tweepy search by location using shapefile

Tags: python, gis, tweepy

I'm on a project trying to analyze spatial distribution of Tweets. I don't want to depend on the geotaged Twitters, as they are very rare.

My idea is to input a shapefile and use each feature of it to serve as a location filter and loop to the number of Tweets for every feature of my shapefile.

I need help structuring my loop.

Comment: If you have any idea of how to use shapefiles as location filter it will be very apreciated!